# Catching Angular promise success response twice

Tags: angularjs

It seems that the console output will always be:

```
This is the first response
This is the second response
```

because the success function of the inner method will be invoked first. Is this a correct assumption? Is the order guaranteed?

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope,$http) {

    var getUrl = function () {

          var config = {
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'some.txt'
          };


          return $http(config)
              .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {

                   console.log('This is the first response');

              })
              .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              });

     };   



    var init = function () {
        var promise = getUrl();
        promise.then(
           function() { 
              console.log('This is the second response');
           });
    };

    init();

 });
```

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct. The function is called `then()` for a good reason ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because $http return a promise itself and what you do above is promise chaining.

Although it might be better to use $http.then(success,error).then(success,error);